# Backpropagation of Bias in Neural networks

Tags: backpropagation, bias

My goal is to calculate backpropagation(Especially the backpropagation of the bias).

For example, X, W and B are python numpy array, such as [[0,0],[0,1]] , [[5,5,5],[10,10,10]] and [1,2,3] for each. And, suppose dL/dY is [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].

How to calculate dL/dB? Answer should be [5, 7, 9]. why is it calculated that way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you provided already shows how to calculate the derivative of the loss with regards to the biases, it is equal to the derivative of the loss with regards to the y values. The only thing you have to do is take the sum of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}$ over the number of samples, which gives you $\frac{\partial L}{\partial B} = [1 + 4, 2 + 5, 3 + 6] = [5, 7, 9]$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May i have further question? Why the derivative of dL/dB  become the sum of the elements?

Comment: You could see the bias as a multiplication of the bias vector `(N, 3)` with a vector of ones `(1, 3)` since the bias is simply added. Then when performing backpropagation $\frac{\partial L}{\partial B}$ is equal to $[[1, 1, 1]] * \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}$ (`(1, N) * (N, 3)`), which effectively performs the sum over the number of samples and returns a matrix of shape `(1, 3)`.